# Weird step in counting sort from Intro to Algorithms

Tags: algorithm, sorting

This seems to be a very common book (Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein) so hopefully someone will be able to assist.  In chapter 8, the algorithm for counting sort is given.  It makes sense where you have the input array A and you find the range from 0 to k for the size that array C will be.  C[i] is then made to contain the number of elements in A equal to i.  For example:

```
A: [2,5,3,0,2,3,0,3]
C: [2,0,2,3,0,1]
```

But after this they make it so that C[i] contains the number of elements less than or equal to i.  For example:

```
C: [2,2,4,7,7,8]
```

Why is this necessary?  Couldn't you just iterate through the original C and have a sorted array from that?  You know the exact count of each number so you could just go in order putting the right amount of each number in B and have a sorted array.  Does transforming C from the first form to the second form somehow make it stable?

Comment: I assume you mean [Cormen, Leiserson, Rivest, Stein](http://mitpress.mit.edu/books/introduction-algorithms)? There's also a [Wikipedia page for the Counting Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: @Steve314 Yes, that's the one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose you are proposing to do the following with the intermediate `C` (using index 1 arrays):

```
i = 1
for k = 1 to len(C)
  for j = 1 to C[i]
    B[i] = k
    i = i + 1
```

This seems to be reasonable, and has the same asymptotic running time. However, consider the case where the items whose keys you are sorting on are not just single integers, but have some other data attached to them. The counting algorithm makes the sort stable; relative orders of items with same keys are preserved (see [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)). You lose the ability to sort general data if you just assign the output from the indices of `C`. Hence why the sort assigns elements via `B[C[A[j]]] <- A[j]`.

For others who are curious, this is the completion of the original algorithm:

```
# C[i] now contains the number of elements equal to i.
for i = 1 to k
  C[i] <- C[i] + C[i-1]
# C[i] now contains the number of elements less than or equal to i.
for j = length[A] downto 1
  B[C[A[j]]] <- A[j]
  C[A[j]] <- C[A[j]] - 1
```

To explain the decrement in the last part, I cite the book, which also explains the stability of the sort:

> Because the elements might not be distinct, we decrement `C[A[j]]` each time we place a value `A[j]` into the `B` array. Decrementing `C[A[j]]` causes the next input element with a value equal to `A[j]`, if one exists, to go to the position immediately before `A[j]` in the output array.

Also, if we did that, I guess we wouldn't be able to call it `COUNTING-SORT` anymore because it wouldn't be counting the number of items less than any particular item in the input array (as they define it). :)

Comment: Yea that's essentially what I'm proposing.  I thought the name `COUNTING-SORT` referred to how it counts the number of `i` and stores it at `C[i]`.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked something. There is a good reason for why we must do the cumulative sum :)

Comment: Once you store just the cumulative frequency in C, don't you lose the relative orders of the same keys?  It's obvious to see it in action for something like radix sort, but it doesn't make sense here because we are only storing a raw count.

Comment: No, the keys are still ordered in the original array `A`. When we decrement values in the final `C[A[j]]`, we ensure that we are placing the sorted items in the same order.

Comment: OK I think that makes more sense then.  Thanks.

Comment: There appears to be an error in the completion you posted. Shouldn't the bounds of the loop used to calculate the prefix sum (for i = 1 to k) be 2 to k and not 1 to k?